# Listado de una clase que pertenece a una interfaz

Tags: c#

Suponiendo, tengo las siguientes clases:

```
public class OrquestadorModelBase
{
    //otros parámetros por aquí...
    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public IOrquestadorBody Body { get; set; }
}

public class PlantOrquestadorModel : IOrquestadorBody
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
string json = "[{'Code':'3500','Name':'CHIAPA DE CORZO'}]"
OrquestadorModelBase orquestadorBase = new OrquestadorModelBase();
                List<PlantOrquestadorModel> plantSync = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<PlantOrquestadorModel>>(json);
                orquestadorBase.Body = plantSync; //error aquí
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'List' to
> 'IOrquestadorBody'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
> cast?)

Sé que no voy a poder hacerlo porque un listado de la clase no hereda la interfaz directamente, pero es precisamente lo que busco entender, cómo puedo hacer que `List<PlantOrquestadorModel>` Sea compatible con `OrquestadorModelBase.Body` que es de tipo `IOrquestadorBody`?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, incluye el json que estás recibiendo y de paso, cambia el nombre de la variable de AddPlantOrquestradorModel a PlantOrquestradorModel, el motivo es simple: los verbos indican métodos. Saludos.

Comment: listo hermano, gracias! :D

Comment: Intenta poner el nullable: `public IOrquestadorBody Body`